# Using RevolutionPlot3D to Plot in a Cylindrical Coordinate System

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

It is not entirely clear how to plot functions in a cylindrical coordinate system `(ρ, ϕ, z)` using `RevolutionPlot3D`.

How can I plot the following function?

```
V[ρ_, z_] := -(1/Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2]) - (3 E^(-3 Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2]) + 
 E^(-7 Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2]))/Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2] + ρ^2
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that `RevolutionPlot3D` can only plot a surface. Now there are three variable `ρ, z,θ` in  `V[ρ, z]`,we use `ParametricRegion` to plot such solid instead.

```
V[ρ_, 
   z_] = -(1/Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2]) - (3 E^(-3 Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2]) + 
      E^(-7 Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2]))/Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2] + ρ^2;
reg = ParametricRegion[{ρ*Cos[θ], ρ*Sin[θ], 
    V[ρ, z]}, {{ρ, 0, 2}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {z, -3, 
     3}}];
Region[reg, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[`RevolutionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html) plots a *surface*, while you have a scalar function in 3D, $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$. Therefore, you should use [`DensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot3D.html), [`ContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html), [`SliceDensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html) or [`SliceCountourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceCountourPlot3D.html).

For transforming coordinates, you can use [`CoordinateTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateTransform.html).

```
Clear[V];
V[ρ_, θ_, z_] := -(1/Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2]) - (3 E^(-3 Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2]) +
       E^(-7 Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2]))/Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2] + ρ^2;

V = V @@ CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Cylindrical", {x, y, z}]
(* x^2 + y^2 - 1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - (
 E^(-7 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]) + 3 E^(-3 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]))/Sqrt[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2] *)

DensityPlot3D[V, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
ContourPlot3D[V, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, Contours -> 7, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
SliceDensityPlot3D[V, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]
SliceContourPlot3D[V, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]
```

[image]