# How could a function in a cylindrical coordinate system be plotted?

Tags: plotting, graphics, numerics, graphics3d

Below is the code for finding the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of a particle in the Coulomb field using NDEigensystem. The problem is solved in cylindrical coordinates ($\rho,\theta,z$; $\rho \in [0,\infty)$, $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, $z \in [-\infty,\infty]$).

How could the 3D graphs of the first five eigenfunctions (`funs[[1]]`,`funs[[2]]`,`funs[[3]]`,`funs[[4]]`,`funs[[5]]`,) be plotted in cylindrical coordinates?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
\[Rho]max = 10;
zmax = 10;
HC = Simplify[-1/2*
     Laplacian[u[\[Rho], z], {\[Rho], \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"] - 
    1/Sqrt[\[Rho]^2 + z^2]*u[\[Rho], z]];
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[HC + u[\[Rho], z], 
   u[\[Rho], z], {\[Rho], 0, \[Rho]max}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 10, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "MaxIterations" -> 10000}}];

(*eigenvalues*)
Sort[vals - 1] 
(*{-0.500523, -0.133734, -0.128976, -0.067941, -0.067371, -0.0543117, \
-0.0180998, 0.0111246, 0.0282921, 0.0553687}*)

(*eigenfunctions*)
funs[[1]]
(*InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{0.,10.},{-10.,10.}}
Output: scalar

][\[Rho],z]*)
funs[[2]]
(*InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{0.,10.},{-10.,10.}}
Output: scalar

][\[Rho],z]*)
funs[[3]];funs[[4]];funs[[5]];
```

Comment: Aren't $\rho$ and $z$ equivalent to rectangular coordinates on a sheet of constant $\theta$?  Do you want something different from what comes out when you plot (for example) `ContourPlot[funs[[3]], {\[Rho], 0, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]` (or `DensityPlot` with the same arguments)?

Comment: @Michael Seifert, thanks! Yes, but I'd like to get a 3D graph (Plot3D)

Comment: @MamMam, you have posted [the same question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286547/using-revolutionplot3d-to-plot-in-a-cylindrical-coordinate-system) a month ago and also received an answer. Is there any particular reason for asking the same question again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, we can just substitute it into the given eigenfunctions and feed the result into Mathematica plotting functions like `ContourPlot3D` or `DensityPlot3D` that expect Cartesian components.  For example:

```
ContourPlot3D[funs[[5]] /. {\[Rho] -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, 
              {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, {z, -10, 10}, 
              PlotRange -> All, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> {10, 20, 5}]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot3D[
  funs[[5]]^2 /. {\[Rho] -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, 
  {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {10, 20, 5}]
```

[image]

(Note that this second diagram plots $\psi^2$ instead of $\psi$, i.e., the probability density rather than the wavefunction amplitude.)

Comment: Thank you very much!